# apply a flask code to an environment which are stored in different directory

Tags: python, flask

I need to apply a flask code to an environment which are stored in a different directory when I use :

`set FLASK_APP=C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dl_env\k.py`

This error raised:

> flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "'C".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
set FLASK_APP=C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/dl_env/k.py
```